# react-native keyboardDidShow/keyboardDidHide keyboard events not firing

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm tring to make use of the keyboard events on android by using the `keyboardDidShow/keyboardDidHide` events but none are firing. Am I not subscribing correctly?

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.2",

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    keyboard: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidShow',
      this.handleKeyboardState(true),
    );
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidHide',
      this.handleKeyboardState(false),
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
  }

  handleKeyboardState(state) {
    console.log('WILL SET KEYBOARD STATE TO', state);
    this.setState({keyboard: state});
  } 

...
}
```

I mean they do fire, but exactly when the component is mounted and the functions are executed

```
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (1/1), done.

 LOG  Running "Test app" with {"rootTag":21}
 LOG  false
 LOG  WILL SET KEYBOARD STATE TO true
 LOG  WILL SET KEYBOARD STATE TO false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are not using the correct callback signature for your listeners. Could you try the following:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidShow',
      () => this.handleKeyboardState(true),
    );
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidHide',
      () => this.handleKeyboardState(false),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. That was it.